# Can we track using google analytics, how much time user spending in application

Tags: android, google-analytics, titanium, titanium-mobile

android app developed using titanium sdk, my question, can we track how much time user spending on particular app,

i m using Google analytic 1.0 to track the user activities.below code :

```
var GA = require('main').getGoogleAnalytics();

    GA.trackEvent({

        category : "Login",

        action : "PageLoad",

        label : 'ForgotPassword',

        value : 1

    });

    GA.trackScreen("Login");
```

If yes, can anyone help me with the code pls?else give some other way?
thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Quick search int the [Appcelerator Marketplace](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/listing?q=analytics#!/list/page/1/search=google%20analytics) I found at least 3 modules: 2 are free (one of them open source) and one paid. You'll have to figure out what better suits your needs.

You can also write your own Titanium module.

I would try to use one of the free ones to see if it suits your needs, and if not try the paid one.